# how to change url for javascript in opencart

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, opencart

i have been working on the opencart frontend. And i want to make a frontend structure such that products uploaded by a particular vendor is shown. For that i use the url 'user/vendor_name'. And i have made changes in htaccess file for such url and after that i have changed the link function in url.php file for such cases. So now if a user clicks anywhere in the website the url will show 'user/vendor_name/index.php......'. But the url in javascript doesnt use $this->link function and those changes of url.php file doesnot take effect and thus it redirects to the original url.
Please help me out on this.

Comment: Any code of what you have tried?

Comment: In the link function of url.php in system/library i used this code
'  
  if(Vendor_name != '')
   $url .='user/'.Vendor_name.'/';
  
  $url .= 'index.php?route=' . $route;
'
where if user/vendor_name is encountered i defined vendor_name and thus the url changes accordingly.
I dont know about at which function does url from javascript redirect to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to modify the controllers for each template containing such URLs and make sure You are setting a vendor name to a PHP variable accessible by the template:

```
$this->data['vendor'] = $vendor_information['name'];
```

supposing the vendor name is stored in a variable `$vendor_name` under the index `name`. This is only an example. Now in each template identify such URL with the JS part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add' // + ...
    // ...
});
```

and change it to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'vendor/<?php echo $vendor; ?>/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add' // + ...
    // ...
});
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: i have tried this solution and it solves the problem to a certain limit but not completely. I am actually using a search box in header file so after using this code it does give the desired the result and the url becomes 'user/vendor_name'. But once it is redirected to the search result page and if we again use the search box it again redirects to the original url without user/vendor_name.

Comment: Then You have to fix the problem at the search page - take a look into `catalog/controller/product/search.php` and/or `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/product/search.tpl` and search for problem there.  In my answer I am mentioning You would have to fix ALL the controllers and ALL the templates that uses the *old* URL format... Also make sure You are not using any third-party extension for search...

Comment: well i have tried this solution as well but it doesnt work because changing anything in search.tpl or controller/search.php has no effect on what is going on in the header file. The search options is in the header which is naturally called in all files. And interesting i checked the url in the javascript and it showed the correct path i.e user/vendor_name and still its redriecting to the original url. I have no idea why it doing this only when we are using the search button for the second time..

Comment: Then, check the `catalog/controller/common/header.php` and it's template please.

Comment: well as it turns out changing the search.tpl and controller/search.php did the trick. Thanks for the solution.